# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppDao':

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a dao class which has a dependency on another utility class `AuditStore`.

```
package myapp;
@Repository
public class MyAppHibernateDao {

    @Autowired
    public void setAuditStore(AuditStore auditStore) {
        ConnectorLoggingHelper.setAuditStore(auditStore);
    }

}
```

The AuditStore.java

```
package myapp;
@Resource
public class AuditStore {
    //too many dependencies in this class including db connection 
}
```

Now I want to write integration test for the dao class which don't cover functionalities of 'AuditStore'.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring-myapp-db-connector-test.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyAppHibernateDaoIntegrationTest {


    @Test
    public void test() {
        //test code here
    }
}
```

and my xml config file is

```
<!--spring-myapp-db-connector-test.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <!-- enable autowiring -->

 <context:annotation-config/>

 <bean id="myAppDao" class="myapp.MyAppHibernateDao">

</beans>
```

Whe I run this I am getting following errors.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuditStore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'myapp.AuditStore' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The `AuditStore` is a very complex object and  I don't use this classes functionality for testing  (I need a `null` or mock of this class). Is there any way I can avoid creating a bean of `AuditStore` defined in xml and make things work.

I know that making `@Autowired(required = false)` would work, that would make change in the application code for test, so I am looking for other options.

Please help if there is any alternative.

Comment: You already answered your own question... Use a mock.

Comment: How to define this mock object of class AuditStore in xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible you should consider moving to annotation driven configuration and use something like `@InjectMock`. However, assuming you are required to stick with the approach you outlined in your question, you can define a mock instance of `MyAppHibernateDao` in `spring-myapp-db-connector-test.xml` in several ways:

- [Use a factory bean](https://blog.jayway.com/2011/11/30/spring-integration-tests-part-i-creating-mock-objects/)
- Use [Springockito](http://www.springockito.org/). And, of course,
- Declare the `myAppDao` bean in `spring-myapp-db-connector-test.xml` as follows:

  ```
  <bean id="myAppDao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
      <constructor-arg value="myapp.MyAppHibernateDao"/>
  </bean>
  ```

You can then `@Autowire MyAppHibernateDao` into `MyAppHibernateDaoIntegrationTest` and set expectations etc on it in your test/setup methods.

Comment: The idea is to mock AuditStore and not MyAppHibernateDao, but this approach works, Thank you very much.